# Let $\theta : V \rightarrow V$ be an idempotent linear map. $W = \text{ker }\theta$. if $\theta$ not identity map, prove $W \neq \{0_v\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\theta : V \rightarrow V$ be an idempotent linear map. $W = \text{ker }\theta$. if $\theta$ not identity map, prove $W \neq \{0_v\}$

I think I might have solved it, but I just need my proof checked:

\begin{align}
\text{let } x \in W, &\implies \theta(x)=0_v\\
\text{but as }\theta\text{ not the identity map } &\implies x \neq 0_v\\
&\implies W \neq \{0_v\}
\end{align}

would this prove it?

Comment: There are transformations which are not the identity and yet have non-trivial kernel, so your second implication doesn't work. Also, nowhere have you used that $\theta$ is idempotent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $0 \neq x \in V$. If $\theta(x) = 0$ then we're done. Otherwise, consider the element $x-\theta(x)$. I claim that this is nonzero for some $x \in V$ (why?) Now apply $\theta$. What do you get?

Comment: You can say that $x - \theta(x) \neq 0$ as $\theta$ is not the identity map?

Comment: Essentially, yes. To expand on this, if $x - \theta(x) = 0$ for all $x \in V$, then $\theta(x) = x$ for all $x \in V$, and so $\theta$ would be the identity map.

Comment: Okay, and apply $\theta$ gives $\theta(x-\theta(x))=\theta(x)-\theta^2(x)=\theta(x)-\theta(x)=0$? and thus $W \neq \{0_v\}$ thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yup, that's right. And no problem.

Answer (score 2):

The equality $\theta^2 = \theta$ implies that $V = \operatorname{ker}(\theta^2 - \theta) = \operatorname{ker}(\theta-I) \oplus \operatorname{ker}(\theta)$. If $\theta$ is not the identity, then $\ker(\theta - I) \neq V$, so necessarily $\ker{\theta} \neq 0$.